# ElasticSearch JSON query to Pydantic Schema for FastAPI

Tags: json, elasticsearch, schema, fastapi, pydantic

I want to convert the ElasticSearch JSON query to pydantic Schema model for FastAPI. I have tried to convert it but it gives me different query after conversion which ElasticSearch doesn't respond.
Query :

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [  
          {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "JOHN AND ANDY",
            "fields": [FIRST_NAME]
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "SAM",
            "fields": [LAST_NAME]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "height": {
              "gte": 0,
              "lte": 100
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "length1": {
              "gte": 0,
              "lte": 100
            }
          }
          },
          
          {
          "range": {
            "length2": {
              "gte": 0,
              "lte": 100
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "length3": {
              "gte": 0,
              "lte": 100
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "length4": {
              "gte": 0,
              "lte": 100
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me in the conversion? Appreciate it.

Comment: What is the goal of doing ES query validation in FastAPI? Do you want to accept only a single type of ES query? Why does the input need to be in ES format? Are there other ES queries than the one example that should be valid? Should any valid ES query be valid in FastAPI as well?

Comment: Because ES is not able to comprehend the query if it is not in its format. Hence, I am not able to get the results with the converted query.

Comment: But why do you need to validate it in FastAPI if it's submitted verbatim to ES? Couldn't you accept any data in FastAPI, then ask ES to verify the query for you instead of duplicating the effort? (That's why I'm asking about the reason for validating it in FastAPI)

Comment: Actually the workflow is like this : ES Query -> pydantic schema (for backend api) and schema should be similar to query because it will hit the ES database with ES query. I hope it helps to understand.

Comment: Yes, I understand - but why would you need it to fit a pydantic schema (compared to just "accept any structure") - when you can ask ES to validate the query for you in the backend? What is the goal of having an extra validation layer with Pydantic that will need to do everything that the ES query validation layer will have to do anyways?

Comment: The query has different filters and I wanted it to display on the swagger UI of fastAPI so that user can change the range of query accordingly to get the results. Also, pydantic schema is what fastAPI understands. Let me know if you have any other suggestions

Comment: I'd say - just spend an hour or two writing out the Query SQL structure in Pydantic. And then let me know so that I can use it too :)